# Tile Grid with Bindings?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

OK, what I'm trying to do is fairly simple :

- I'm getting a list of images (using bindings) which I'm trying to display in a table-like grid (like 3 images per row)
- How can this be done?

```
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>

           <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="{Binding AlbumArt}"/>

       </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This way, the images are property display, but not the way I want them to - they are display one below the other and not like :

- A B C
- D E F
- G H I

How can this be done? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A great solution would be using `UniformGrid` with its columns property and ItemsControl.
Example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AlbumArt}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="{Binding}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This way you will get the desired result. Read more about UniformGrid here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx)
The reason why your solution does not work, is that Listbox panel puts items one under another, whereas UniformGrid puts them from left to right, until there is available space or has hit the columns limit and then goes down the row.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two StackPanels, one with verticle orientation and one with horizontal. Here's your code edited to include them:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Verticle">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="{Binding AlbumArt}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```